# How to run Rails app with subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run my Rails app like this:

```
rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me
```

The problem is that I am getting the following exception:

```
Exiting
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:233:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

What could be a problem? Thanks.

Comment: How are your subdomains set up? One app with multiple subdomains, or does each subdomain point to a different app?

Comment: @MarsAtomic, one app with multiple subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

Call it like this:

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

then you can visit your page at http://lvh.me:3000/

Comment: Thank you but I receive the message that server can't be find.